# Prevent opting out of certain subscriptions for specific contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, publicationlist

We are using Marketing Cloud for managing outreach to organizations that partner with us through formal agreements and organizations that we are hoping to engage further. The partnering agreement stipulates that the organization cannot opt out of certain emails. Doing so could potentially terminate their partnership.

Is it possible in Marketing Cloud to preclude certain contacts from opting out of certain subscription/publication types? If so, how would this be set up?

Answer (score 4):

According to my understanding there is no built in feature that allows to stop unsubscribing certain subscriber in sfmc.

Although there are various way of doing this:

- **AMPScript (email):** You could setup an AMPScript rule to turn off the unsubscribe link by having a flag in the data (DE) so the link will only be visible to non-targeted subscribers. You can also include your custom preference centre if you have.

For e.g:

```
%%[
VAR @UnsubFlag
SET @UnsubFlag = AttributeValue('unsub_flag_in_data')

IF @UnsubFlag == 'false' AND NOT EMPTY(@UnsubFlag) THEN
<a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</a>
ENDIF
]%%
```

- **CloudPages (custom preference)** You could also setup a custom preference centre to do a [**lookup**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm) on certain Data Extension that holds the targeted subscribers - when one of the targeted subs clicks the unsubscribe link in the email the custom preference will do a lookup on the targeted DE and avoid the subs from unsubscribing.

Like I mentioned that there are various way of doing this but I think hiding the unsubscribe link in the email will be the easiest way to go.